# Put TextBlock inside ToolTip in wpf (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, textblock, mousehover

```
for(int k=0;k<Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Backward.Count;k++){

                _drawing.Children.Add(new Ellipse
                {   ToolTip = "Add your tooltip text here",
                    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                    StrokeThickness = .6,
                    Width = 3,
                    Height = 3,
                    Margin = new Thickness(Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item1, Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item2+PlatformGap*(-k), 0, 0)
                });
                }
```

How do I put this textblock inside a tooltip? The purpose is to view this textblock only on mouse hover. Please suggest any other method also if you find one.

Comment: on what control are you trying to mouse hover on?

Comment: its another object ( ellipse). I want to hover on that object and on doing so should be able to view this textbox.    
     _drawing.Children.Add(new Ellipse
                    {
                        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                        StrokeThickness = .6,
                        Width = 3,
                        Height = 3,
                        Margin = new Thickness(Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item1, Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item2+PlatformGap*(-k), 0, 0)
                    });
                    }

Comment: Ellipse has a tooltip property. Why don't you set that?

Comment: How to exactly? I am not able to get that and that is why I asked this

Answer (score -1):

Ellipse has a tooltip property that you can use:

```
 _drawing.Children.Add(new Ellipse { ToolTip = "Add your tooltip text here", Fill = Brushes.Black, Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = .6, Width = 3, Height = 3, Margin = new Thickness(Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item1, Config.Lines[i].Config.Stations[j].Config.Coordinate.Item2+PlatformGap*(-k), 0, 0) }); }
```

Comment: When you hover over the ellipse, you see nothing?

Comment: Nope. I think we also have to add some kind of control or exact location where this is required.

Comment: no, you don't require that. I tried adding the exact same code on button click and mine works fine. Could you show me the code you used?

Comment: i got the problem! since your ellipse is not filled..your mouse hover cannot find the element..Try setting Ellipse Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black

Comment: what exactly is _drawing?

Comment: a Canvas. And we are adding these elements (ellipse, textblock, lines) in its Children